# c++ how to define a function without knowing the exact parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function

```
template <class T>
void foo() {
  // Within this function I need to create a new T
  // with some parameters. Now the problem is I don't
  // know the number of parameters needed for T (could be
  // 2 or 3 or 4)
  auto p = new T(...);
}
```

How do I solve this? Somehow I remember saw functions with input
like (..., ...)?

Comment: Keywords to look for: varargs, variable length argument list, variadic templates. (However, your code snippet seems strange, there is nothing in there that you could pass to T's constructor.)

Comment: If you don't know the number of parameters, how do you know what values to pass?

Comment: Use this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307939/c-template-function-with-unknown-number-of-arguments

Comment: Use this [link][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307939/c-template-function-with-unknown-number-of-arguments
 
Follow the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working C++11 example for you based on a [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template):

```
#include <utility> // for std::forward.
#include <iostream> // Only for std::cout and std::endl.

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void foo(Args && ...args)
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> p(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

class Bar {
  public:
    Bar(int x, double y) {
        std::cout << "Bar::Bar(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<Bar>(12345, .12345);
}
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: @Xeo: How about now? RAII all the way.

Comment: @Xeo: Oh stop it, you! :-]

Answer (score 6):

You could use variadic templates:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args){

   //unpack the args
   T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

   sizeof...(Args); //returns number of args in your argument pack.
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926674/unpacking-argument-list-with-variadic-template) here has more detail on how to unpack arguments from a variadic template.  This [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) may also provide more information

Comment: You mean `template<class T, class... Args>`. Your edits are not making any sense :-). You need `Args` to be passed to the function, not `T`. Also, use `std::forward` when passing the arguments to the constructor.