# How can I use std::function to accept a function that has different arguments?

Tags: c++, std-function

I have 2 functions, `first_function`, `second_function` that have similar signature. `second_function` takes 2 additional parameters, `x, y`.

I would like to create another function that can take either `first_function` or `second_function` as a parameter.

I was thinking of using `std::function`, but it seems that's restricted to input functions that have the same return type and same arguments? Is there a way to make it work in my case?

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
void first_function(double z) {
  // Implementation not included
}

void second_function(double x, double y, double z) {
  // Implementation not included
}

void compute(first_or_second_function, std::optional<double> x, std::optional<double> y, double z) {

  if (x.has_value()) {
    // invoke second function
    first_or_second_function(x.value, y.value(), z);
  } else {
    // invoke first function
    first_or_second_function(z);
  }

}
```

I am not sure how to create the parameter `first_or_second_function`

Comment: How would you call those functions? More context is needed. What about taking just `F&&` with `template<class F>`?

Comment: Their signatures do not sound very similar to me. How do you expect to be able to use whatever function you pass as an argument if they don't even have the same number of parameters?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example and what are your expectations?

Comment: `variant<function<void(int)>, function<void(int,int,int)>>`

Comment: There is always the fully generic: `template <typename Func, typename... Args) decltype(auto) do_thing(Func&& func, Args&&... args) { return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args...)); }`

Comment: @NathanOliver I plan to use `std::optional` to pass in `x, y`

Comment: @Eljay What is `F&&`?

Comment: *I would like to create another function that can take either first_function or second_function as a parameter.* -- If you can afford the cost of a virtual function, the other alternative could be to wrap those functions into function objects, and have a virtual overload of the call operator, `operator()`.  [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/vPY8xsxoY)

Comment: *What is `F&&`?* Are you familiar with writing templates?  The `F` is a template parameter, intended to be a function (or perhaps any invocable).  It's type is deducted from the function passed into routine.  The `&&` part of `F&&` means it is passed in as a forwarding reference.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, but it's been awhile since I used C++. When I've seen `&&` in the past, it's usually refers to an R-value reference. I don't think I've seen it used in the context of templates. So my understanding here is instead of passing the function as an argument, I should pass it as a template parameter instead?

Comment: The *forwarding reference* `&&` with parameter in template functions are different from the *moving reference* `&&` parameter non-template functions.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just write a simple functionoid yourself?

```
struct function_overloader {
    void operator()(double z) const {
       first_function(z);
    }
    void operator()(double x, double y, double z) const {
       second_function(x, y, z);
    }
};
//and then just use this instead of `std::function<....>`
```

If you want the functions to be replacable, then:

```
struct function_overloader {
    std::function<void(double)> first_function;
    std::function<void(double,double,double)> second_function;

    void operator()(double z) const {
       first_function(z);
    }
    void operator()(double x, double y, double z) const {
       second_function(x, y, z);
    }
};
//and then just use this instead of `std::function<....>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::variant` to pass in the function as a single parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <variant>

using std::cout;
using std::get;
using std::optional;
using std::variant;

namespace {

void first_function(double z) {
    cout << "first_function z:" << z << "\n";
}

void second_function(double x, double y, double z) {
    cout << "first_function x:" << x << " y:" << y << " z:" << z << "\n";
}

using Fn1_t = void(*)(double);
using Fn3_t = void(*)(double,double,double);
using Fn_t = variant<Fn1_t, Fn3_t>;

void compute(Fn_t fn, optional<double> x, optional<double> y, double z) {
    if (x.has_value() && y.has_value()) {
        get<1>(fn)(x.value(), y.value(), z);
    } else {
        get<0>(fn)(z);
    }
}

} // anon

int main() {
    compute(&first_function, {}, {}, 10.0);
    compute(&second_function, 8.2, 9.1, 10.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit uncertain why you would want to pass it to a function and let the function decide instead of calling each function on their own in the if-statement you provided.

I believe the code you are looking for would be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // Shouldn't use this, only for example purposes.

template<typename... Args>
void myFunc(Args... args) {
  cout << "myFunc called with " << sizeof...(args) << " arguments." << endl;
}

template<typename... Args>
void otherFunc(Args... args) {
  cout << "otherFunc called with " << sizeof...(args) << " arguments." << endl;
}

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void callFunc(Func func, Args... args) {
  func(args...);
}

int main() {
  callFunc(&myFunc<double>, 1.0);
  callFunc(&otherFunc<double, double, double>, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if I would *recommend* this solution but it should work.

Output from running the code above:

```
myFunc called with 1 arguments.
otherFunc called with 3 arguments.
```

You should also maybe look at: [C++ template function with unknown number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307939/c-template-function-with-unknown-number-of-arguments) if you are new to templated functions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple overloaded `compute()` should work for you.

```
void compute(double x, double y, double z) {
   second_function(x, y, z);
}

void compute(double z) {
   first_function(z);
}
```

Essentially provide as many overloads of `compute()` as many functions with varying parameters.

You can even have `compute()` templatized on the number of parameters passed in using `if constexpr` like so

```
void first_function(double z) {
    std::cout<<"first_function\n";
}

void second_function(double z, double x, double y) {
    std::cout<<"second_function\n";
}
template <typename ...Args>
void compute(Args... args) {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(args) == 3) {
        second_function(args...);
    } else if constexpr(sizeof...(args) == 1) {
        first_function(args...);
    } else {
        static_assert(false, "no function implemented");
    }
}

int main() {
    compute(1);
    compute(1,2,3);
    compute(1,2); // Fail to compile
}
```